# Blender shows weird artifacts in both cpu and gpu

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

So I tried to create a procedural Minecraft grass shader (still a learner). But found having weird artifacts in both my viewport and render. I tried changing my render to Eevee and still had the same problem. I also tried toggling the show backface, backface culling options, no use. Well, extruding the plane got rid of the other sides except for the bottom face. If someone has a solution or way around this thing, pls help.

[image: The viewport Image]

[Edited]

Changing the scale value to not a whole number kinda works. Yay!
[image: Node Editor]

And also adding arbitrary values to all axis clears the artifacts, but when I change the scale vector node value, it again shows artifacts.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! This is likely because the noise texture behaves weirdly at z = 0. Try adding a vector math node set to add and something like 0.01 along Z. Next time if you will please try to post the node tree as an image instead of having users download the file :)

Comment: @Gorgious Hi, Thanks for answering my question. When I tried adding to the z-axis it still showed the artifacts, but when I tried adding .01 to all axis, it kinda worked. The scale vector math is the problem I think. When I put whole numbers,it shows artifacts. But float values like 15.900 doesn't show the artifacts even without a z-axis arbitary.

Comment: @Gorgious  PS: I just wanted to make sure that there is no amateur setting in my file that caused the problem. So I added the file :) [Kindly Noted]

Comment: BTW your whole setup can be achieved with a voronoi texture with randomness set to 0

Comment: Also, the weird behaviour may very well come from the strange things some people experienced with specific noise values, see my bug report : https://developer.blender.org/T87781 there are some known limitations with noise generation

Comment: Oh, it's a bug. Well, thanks for answering my question stranger. And also thx for the voronoi tip 